# @font-face function not working

Tags: html, fonts, css, embedded-fonts

Can't seem to get this to work in any browser, anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Running live here: http://daveywhitney.com/ford/one/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SackersItalianScriptStdRegula';
    src: url('font/sackersitalianscriptstd-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/sackersitalianscriptstd-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('font/sackersitalianscriptstd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/sackersitalianscriptstd-webfont.svg#webfontkWmYBTH2') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'EngraversMTRegular';
    src: url('font/engr-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/engr-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('font/engr-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/engr-webfont.svg#webfontQUS0Zswo') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}    

#sidetop {
    width:90px;
    height:50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:EngraversMTRegular;
}

#sidetop ul li {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    font-family:EngraversMTRegular;
}

#names {
    width:150px;
    height:250px;
    float:right;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:SackersItalianScriptStdRegula;
    color:#858484;
    margin:0 0 0 50px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths to the font files are not what you have posted here. In the CSS files, your URLs look like this: `url('/font/engr-webfont.eot')`. That means that your font is expected to live at `http://daveywhitney.com/font/engr-webfont.eot`. The leading slash makes the url relative to the server root, not to the style sheet. Rather than having us guess at things, perhaps you could tell us what your directory structure looks like -- where the fonts live in relation to the css file.

Comment: daveywhitney.com/ford/one/font

Comment: Then you'll need to go up a directory before going down to the font; your url should be `url('../font/font-name.ext')`.

Answer (score 1):

The URLs are wrong. For example, I don't get a font file here:

```
http://daveywhitney.com/ford/one/css/font/engr-webfont.woff
```

Comment: my fonts aren't in the css folder, the folder is in the root. Does it have to be in the css folder?